# Communication between two microservices by Docker hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

**How it works now:**

Microservice X makes REST API request to Microservice Y with static ip

```
http://{ip-address}:{port}/doSomething
```

**The problem:**

The problem is that I can no long guarantee that static ip.
I wan't to solve this by using the docker hostname instead:

```
http://hostname:{port}/doSomething
```

I tried achieving this by creating a used defined network in docker-compose:

```
    #part of docker-compose file
    streamapp:
      hostname: twitterstreamapp
      image: twitterstreamapp
      container_name: twitterstreamapp
      restart: always
      ports:
        - '8090:8080'
      build:
        context: ./TwitterStream
        dockerfile: Dockerfile

    storeapp:
      hostname: twitterstoreapp
      image: twitterstoreapp
      container_name: twitterstoreapp
      restart: always
      ports:
        - '8095:8080'
      build:
        context: ./TwitterStore
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      depends_on:
        - 'mysql-db'
      networks:
        - backend

  volumes:
    MyDataVolume:

  networks:
    backend:
      driver: bridge
```

I can ping from Container X to Container Y. But not Curl for example.
How can I fix this, or is this not the best way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution  is very simple, instead of using IPs or Hostnames you can use the service's name.

In your example, in the `streamapp` service you can access the other by using `http://storeapp:8080`.

Similar, in the `storeapp` service you can access the other at `http://streamapp:8080`.

Please not that you must use the internal ports, not the exported ones.

This does not apply when you access the service from the other machines, i.e. from the internet. In that case you must use the form `http://{IP_OF_THE_MACHINE}:8090`

Comment: You are my hero! I didn't realise that I needed to use the internal port. Thank you!

Comment: I would like to do this, in the same machine ?, several nodes, so its posible.. or the easy aproach is do your example.