# Rest communication between two microservices without static ip in Amazon ECS

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-ecs

[In this question, I managed to set-up REST communication between two microservices using a user-defined bridge network in docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534740/communication-between-two-microservices-by-docker-hostname)

Now, I'm trying to do the same when hosting my microservices on AWS.
I could really use some pointers as to how to achieve this, because I'm terribly lost.

I've tried following numerous tutorials, both written and on pluralsight, but none seem to be close enough to my use case.

My project architecture is as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc6TX.png

And my project infrastructure should probably look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X73HA.png

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use internal Loadbalancer for each service and create DNS records us it for app communication Also ECS and a service discovery feature that is useful in this scenario.